# Finding the acceleration given only an angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, acceleration

This is one of my homework problems for a College Physics I course:

> Dana has a sports medal suspended by a long ribbon from her rearview mirror. As she accelerates onto the highway, she notices that the medal is hanging at an angle of 12° from the vertical.
>
> What is her acceleration (m/s<sup>2</sup>)? Express your answer using two significant figures.

What I don't understand is how I'm supposed to calculate anything given only that one angle, 12 degrees. Can someone help guide me to where to get started? Thanks.

Comment: Remember that $\mathbf F$ is a vector, so draw a [free-body diagram](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/newtlaws/Lesson-2/Drawing-Free-Body-Diagrams) for the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a diagram, then you'll find out the answer. If $\mathbf T$ is the tension in the string, $\delta$ is the angle, $m$ is the mass of the medal and $\mathbf g$ is the gravitational acceleration then $$T\cos\delta=mg$$ and $$T\sin\delta=ma$$ where $a$ is the acceleration, then $$\tan\delta=\frac{a}{g}$$ $T, m,\cos\delta\neq 0$ which leads $$a=g\tan\delta$$

If $T$ is equal to $0$ then the mass of the medal would be $0$, the same would happen if $\cos\delta=0$. Now, if $\sin\delta=0$ then there would not be acceleration at all ($m$ cannot be zero).